# AWS VPN server cost

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-web-services, mikrotik

This question is probably naive - please bear with me, I'm still getting my head around how VPNs work.

**TL;DR - if I host a VPN server on an EC2 instance (standalone, not VPC), will I pay $.05/hr for every device connected to it?**

We are considering hosting our VPN server on an AWS EC2 instance. There will likely be hundreds of connected clients, but very little data transfer. I'm concerned because of the pricing information in AWS' VPC overview with regards to VPN connections (http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/#pricing). It reads "$0.05 per VPN Connection-hour"

However AWS' suggested use case is establishing a VPN connection to a VPC so that it may be used as an extension of onsite IT infrastructure, which I don't think applies in our situation (described below). Subsequently I'm wondering if that .05/connection/hour pricing model applies. Also our VPN server will not (or at least does not need to be) in a VPC -- a standalone EC2 instance will be more than enough.

Our use case, in the event that it's helpful: We need to maintain a VPN connection with  (MikroTik) routers installed at a number of separate physical locations to periodically push configuration updates.

Comment: Three downvotes with no comments? Anyone willing to explain why?

Comment: Likely because you're asking about pricing, and we can't tell you how Amazon's pricing works with any real level of certainty. This is something you really need to ask ***Amazon*** (and they may ask you deep probing questions about your use case before telling you how much it's all going to cost you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VPN you're looking at isn't for clients; it's for integrating the VPC environment into your internal network. You can use any type of VPN server (say, hosted on an EC2 instance) for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan C - I really appreciate the clarification. It was important to verify before making what seemed like it could be a very expensive mistake.